# Transfer timestamps between .srt subtitle files

Tags: video, subtitles

Assuming I have two subtitle files with .srt extension,

1. ENGLISH_DVD.srt - Subtitles in English language obtained from a DVD
2. TURKISH_TV.srt - Subtitles in Turkish language obtained from a TV broadcast

Also assuming these two .srt files are synced for videos different FPS or length.

How can I combine these two files such that the resulting file has the timestamps from the ENGLISH_DVD and has the actual subtitle content from TURKISH_TV, so that I can watch the DVD version with Turkish subtitles?

edit: I know about "linear time correction" method but it did not produce satisfactory results for me.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to sync the timestamps for both before attempting a merge? Otherwise you're going to end up with the Turkish subs out of sync with the action on screen.

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking: I have 10 timestamps (from English file) and 10 subtitle lines (from Turkish file), so I want to merge them... haven't really thought about syncing.

Comment: are the number of timestamps, equal in the both subtitle files? could you upload them?